# Безопасная запись файла в php

Tags: php, файлы, запись

Сразу оговорюсь, что я знаю как работать с БД, но в данном случае необходимо хранить данные именно в файле.

Скрипт периодически считывает и записывает данные в файл. На случай, если страницу откроют одновременно несколько человек и скрипт так же параллельно запустится несколько раз, я блокирую запись в файл с помощью LOCK_EX

```
// считываю файл
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

// провожу необходимые изменения контента

// записываю файл
file_put_contents($filename, $content, LOCK_EX);
```

Но, как выяснилось, этот вариант не работает. Во время записи в одном потоке, другой поток может начать считывать файл, считает его не полностью, т.к. первый поток еще не закончил запись, и снова записать уже не полный файл.

В связи с этим вопрос, как правильно заблокировать файл, чтобы другие потоки ждали завершения операции первым потоком?

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что file_put_contents сначала удаляет файл, а потом начинает писать новый, не заблокированный. Поэкспериментируй просто с блокировками, не пытаясь его писать. Если блокировки работают - то блокируй какой нибудь другой файл - что будет показывать что ты пишешь основной

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899737/should-lock-ex-on-both-read-write-be-atomic) на англ. SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать еще один файл для хранения признака блокировки файла с данными. Каждый поток перед началом работы с файлом данных проверяет наличие (или содержимое файла блокировки (например, my_file.lock) и пока файл существует, делать кратковременный sleep и повтор попытки.